# How can we disable delete and rename option of the context menu of excel at the sheet level

Tags: c#-3.0, vsto

My requirement is that, I need to *disable the Delete and Rename option* at the **sheet level** and not at the overall application/workbook level.

I have done the below in the **ThisWorkbook_Startup event of the Workbook.cs** file

```
Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.CommandBars["Ply"].Controls["&Delete"].Enabled = false;
Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.CommandBars["Ply"].Controls["&Rename"].Enabled = false;
```

But this code is applicable at the overall workbook level. Say I want to perform the same only for Sheet1 and not for other sheets.

How can we do it?

I am using Excel VSTO 2007 and C# is the language

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. We need to invoke the method **DisableContextMenuItems()** from *Workbook's Startup and SheetActivated Event*.

Startup event will be called for the very first time when the Addin will be loaded. And for every sheet change or activated, the SheetActivate event will be fired.

```
private void ThisWorkbook_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

   DisableContextMenuItems();

}

void ThisWorkbook_SheetActivate(object Sh)
{
   DisableContextMenuItems(); 
}

private static void DisableContextMenuItems()
{
   var sheet = Globals.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet as ExcelXP.Worksheet;
   var name = sheet.Name;

    if (name != "Sheet1")
    {
       Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.CommandBars["Ply"].Controls["&Delete"].Enabled = true;
       Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.CommandBars["Ply"].Controls["&Rename"].Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
       Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.CommandBars["Ply"].Controls["&Delete"].Enabled = false;
       Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.CommandBars["Ply"].Controls["&Rename"].Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Thanks